# Erlang script not sending data back to client

Tags: sockets, erlang

I am new to erlang language and have a script which accepts data from client and stores response in log. I want to do some modifications in it so that it can send response back to client. I have tried putting ranch:send(Socket, Data); in http_pool where ladger.info is written but error is coming. Please help

```
 main() ->
    { ok, _ } = application:ensure_all_started(?APP),
    %% t:t(),
    ok.
start(_StartType, _StartArgs) ->
  { ok, Pid } = avant_app_sup:start_link(),

  http_pool:init(),

  {ok, _} = ranch:start_listener(tcp_handler, 10,
        ranch_tcp, [
          {port, env(tcp_port)},
          {max_connections, infinity}
    ], tcp_handler, []),

  file:write_file("server.pid", os:getpid()),

  { ok, Pid }.

stop(_State) ->
  ok.

env(Key) ->
  { ok, Value } = application:get_env(?APP, Key),
  Value.
```

---

http_pool

```
-define(POOL, ?MODULE).

init() ->
  ok = hackney_pool:start_pool(?POOL, [
    {timeout, 150000},
    {max_connections, avant_app:env(api_pool_size)}
  ]),
  ok.

request(Binary) ->
  URL = avant_app:env(api_url),
  Headers = [],
  Payload = { form, [{ <<"data">>, Binary }] },
  Options = [
    {connect_options, [ binary ]},
    {pool, ?POOL}
  ],
  {ok, 200, _RespHeaders, ClientRef} = hackney:request(post, URL, Headers, Payload, Options),
  { ok, Body } = hackney:body(ClientRef),
  lager:info("Body ~p", [ Body ]),
  ok.
```

---

```
-behaviour(ranch_protocol).

-export([
  start_link/4,init/4
]).

-record(state, {
  socket :: reference(),
  transport :: module(),
  rest = <<>> :: binary()
}).

start_link(Ref, Socket, Transport, Opts) ->
    Pid = spawn_link(?MODULE, init, [Ref, Socket, Transport, Opts]),
    {ok, Pid}.

init(Ref, Socket, Transport, _Opts = []) ->
    ok = ranch:accept_ack(Ref),
    loop(#state{
      socket = Socket,
    transport = Transport
    }).

loop(State = #state{ transport = Transport, socket = Socket }) ->
  case parse(State) of
    { ok, Str, NewState } ->
      queue_server:add(Str),
      loop(NewState);
    { nothing, NewState } ->
      case Transport:recv(Socket, 0, 60000) of
        {ok, Data} ->
              lager:info("i got ~p", [ Data ]),
          loop(NewState#state{ rest = <<(NewState#state.rest)/binary, Data/binary>> });
        { error, timeout } ->
          loop(NewState);
        _Any ->
          %%lager:info("Socket ~p", [ Any ]),
          ok = Transport:close(Socket)
      end;
    {exit, _Reason } ->
      ok = Transport:close(Socket)
  end.

parse(State) ->
  parse(State#state.rest, State).

parse(<<>>, State) -> { nothing, State#state{ rest = <<>> }};
parse(<<"S", _/binary>> = Packet, State) ->
  case binary:split(Packet, <<"END">>) of
    [ Str, Rest ] ->
      { ok, <<Str/binary, "END">>, State#state{
        rest = Rest
      }};
    [ Rest ] ->
      { nothing, State#state{
        rest = Rest
      }}
  end;
parse(Data, State) ->
  case binary:split(Data, <<"END">>) of
    [ _, Rest ] ->
      parse(<<"END", Rest/binary>>, State);
    [ _Rest ] ->
      parse(<<>>, State)
  end.
```

Comment: I don't see `tcp_handler` implementation.

Comment: @Hynek-Pichi-Vychodil added now

Comment: "but error is coming" what error exactly?